# phonegap ios: push notification freezes when user selected "Don't Allow" for the permission request box

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova, push-notification

I have followed the example to install the push notification plugin for my ios Phonegap app. When I open my app, the push notification permission request box was shown. It works perfectly when I select "OK". But when I select "Don't Allow", my app freezes and the console log shown "Attempting to badge the application icon but haven't received permission from the user to badge the application".

please help...Thank you.

Comment: It looks like your app is trying to take advantage of push permissions despite not being granted them. Is it possible at all to modify the code because it sounds like it just needs to add a check for permissions?

Answer (score 0):

On the file .../YOUR_PROJECT/platforms/ios/YOUR_PROJECT/YOUR_PROJECT-info.plist

Put these lines obeying the tags

```
<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
<array>
  <string>remote-notification</string>
</array>
```